# What kind of accent is this?

Tags: american-english, accent

What kind of accent is **[this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLRwpnkGHrQ)**? Is the speaker there speaking American English or Canadian? It is quite obvious it's not British or Australian accent. If it's American, can you, please, say what part of the USA it is?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know it would ask to install plugin.

Comment: @chaos: Okay, I just downloaded this video and uploaded it on youtube and changed the link in my question, so now there will be no plugin requests.

Comment: At some points, it almost sounds like the guy isn't a native speaker. But I can't for the life of me identify what his accent is.

Comment: @Matha: “we mentioned couple of strategies” – omitting the indefinite article … that’s *definitely* not a native speaker. Sounds East European to me.

Comment: I have to agree with @Konrad here. I think it will be very hard to get more specific than Eastern European, but it's quite obvious this person does not speak English natively.

Comment: For me it sounds like russian accent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am no expert, but it sounds to me like his first language is a European one. His pronunciation of some words is similar to people from the Balkans or other Eastern European nations. Spain is a wild card. There's a hint of Irish in there too, but it's not full-on. The clues for me are:

> "Strategies", (0:40), Spanish,
>   Bosnian, Croatian?
>
> "Skimming", he pronounces it
>   skee-ming."Beginning",too (0:51);
>   bee-gee-ning.
>
> "look" - pronounced thickly, similar
>   to Irish maybe?
>
> "tell us" (2:40), slight Irish
>   inflection?
>
> "about luck" (2:43), an Eastern
>   European inflection?
>
> "ok" (2:47), Spanish inflection?

Most of his oks sound like how a Spanish person would say them.

> "daily situation" (2:57), very close
>   to a Bosnian inflection.

If you ever find out, do let us know.

Apologies to the Spanish, Irish, Bosnians, Croatians and anyone from Eastern Europe if I've got it wrong.:-)

Comment: @Sky Red: WOW!!! Thank you for your detailed answer. I just got a way of finding out where that speaker is originally from and will do it in about 7 hours. As soon as I know, I'll let you know here.

Comment: He is not Spanish or Irish. Deduction, not induction.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I agree; he's definitely not Irish. In some words, there's just a hint of similarity with the Irish accent.

Comment: @brilliant: I'll check in then; I hope I nail this.

Comment: @Sky Red: All right, I've found out. The guy is Russian. I am so surprised, I am myself Russian, but not only did I fail to detect Russian accent in his speech I even thought he was a native English speaker! It just proves I am quite hard on hearing :)

Comment: @brilliant: Wow, I should have moved even further east; I would never have guessed. Congratulations to everyone who nailed it as Russian; you guys are good.

Comment: Definitely Russian l:s; he also omits articles the way many Russians do

Answer (score 7):

There are word choices that make me think the speaker's native language is not English. There are words that are not pluralized that should be and other words seem to be dropped.

The "para" in paragraph has hints of Russian as the speakers native language. Listen to the long O sound in the way he says story.

Comment: @Jason Aller: "The "para" in paragraph has hints of Russian as the speakers" - Can you, please, describe what exactly in "para" sounds different there?

Comment: @Jason Aller: "Listen to the long O sound in the way he says story" - Do you mean the speaker there is making this vowel sound as a long "o" vowel (like in "foal" and "mole")? As far as I know the vowel "o" in the word "story" is not a long "o".

Comment: The first a in paragraph had a different sound to it. I choose my words poorly in describing the way the o sounded in the word story. I should have said that the speaker sounded that o for longer in the word story, not that it was a long o.

Comment: 100% Russian. Also he is apparently now in China, suggesting he crossed the land border.

Comment: Check out "Russian Nine" from here http://web.ku.edu/~idea/europe/russia/russia.htm